# JavaScript: вставить div блок

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в JavaScript(без использования jQuery и пр. библиотек) вставить  такой html блок:

```
     <div id="id1">
        <span class="class1"> Текст1 </span>
    </div>
```

Вставить нужно в конец блока main:

```
   <div id="main">
        <div id="id2">
           <span class="class2"> Текст2 </span>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Пробую сделать так:

```
  var main= document.getElementById("main");
      main.appendChild('<div id="id1"><span class="class1"> Текст1 </span> </div>');
```

Но возникает ошибка.
Видимо нужно DIV создать через `CreateElement`, ему усановить `setAttribute("id", "id1")`, и затем через `.InnerHTML` добавить `<span class="class1"> Текст1 </span>`. Это как-то сложно. Можно ли сделать проще?

Спасибо!

Comment: для этого и придумана жуйквери))

Comment: вам два раза createelement, сначала спан, потом див, в него вставить спан, затем див в ставить в main, больше инфы https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document

Comment: Можно через main.innerHTML+= "<div...>"; Многие так делают, но это приводит к полному обновлению всего содержимого дива main, если там было выделение или поле ввода с введённой пользователем информацией, они потеряются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```js
 var main= document.getElementById("main");
 var str = '<div id="id1"><span class="class1"> Текст1 </span> </div>';
  
      main.innerHTML += str;
```

```html
<div id="main">
        <div id="id2">
           <span class="class2"> Текст2 </span>
       </div>
   </div>
```

поменять местами:

```js
 var main= document.getElementById("main");
 
 var str = '<div id="id1"><span class="class1"> Текст1 </span> </div>';
  
      main.innerHTML = str + main.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="main">
        <div id="id2">
           <span class="class2"> Текст2 </span>
       </div>
   </div>
```